# Use value of variable A to get variable B

Tags: vba, variables, excel

My variables: `answer_a, answer_b, answer_c, question_letter`

The variable `question_letter` is set by the user. Depending on if they enter `a`, `b`, or `c`, I want to get `answer_a`, `answer_b`, or `answer_c`, respectively.

Because there will be significantly more than three `answer_` variables later, I'd like to do something like this: `answer_ & question_letter`, but this doesn't compile.

How can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: Your best bet is probably to use an array (and calculate an index depending on user input) or a Dictionary to map the user input with some other variables.

Comment: Is there any way to do something like `answer_ & question_letter`?

Comment: Can't do dynamic variable names in VBA

Comment: Can anybody provide an example of how to accomplish this a different way, then? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this. One might be to use a case statement:

```
Select Case question_letter
    Case a
        code
    Case b 
        more code
    Case else
        code if nothing matches
End Select
```

Comment: Now if you were using a database to store the question number, letter and answer pairs then you could just query the database and return what you wanted then.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is an array:

```
Dim answer() as String    ' An empty array
ReDim answer(1 to 3)      ' Set the array to 3 "cells"
Dim ansReturn as String
...
Select Case question_letter
    case "a"
        ansReturn = answer(1)
    case "b"
        ansReturn = answer(2)
    case "c"
        ansReturn = answer(3)
    case else
        ansReturn = ""
End Select
```

You can set the array to any arbitrary (positive integer) size.

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> References and add *Microsoft Scripting Runtime*. This will allow you to use a Dictionary that associates a ket with a value;

```
Private answers As Dictionary

Sub callMeAtStartup()
    '// setup answers
    Set answers = New Dictionary
    answers.Add "a", "111"
    answers.Add "b", "222"
    answers.Add "c", "333"
End Sub

Function lookup(char As String) As String
    If answers.Exists(char) Then lookup = answers(char)
End Function

Sub test()
    callMeAtStartup
    '....
    Dim answer As String
    answer = lookup("f")
    If Len(answer) Then MsgBox "Its " & answer
End Sub
```

As an alternative for 26 choices or less map the letter to an array index

```
dim answers(3) as String
answers(0) = "111" '//a
answers(1) = "222"
answers(2) = "333" '//c

question_letter = "b"

'//char to index
index = asc(ucase$(question_letter)) - 65
if index < ubound(answers) Then
    msgbox answers(index)
end if
```